# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method boundingRect(Lorg/opencv/core/Mat;)

Tags: java, android, opencv

I have some Android code that needs to find contours and outline them with rectangles. I have no problems with OpenCV initialization (all other functions work fine). But when I run `Imgproc.boundingRect(contours.get(i));` error `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError` occurs.

```
2021-09-03 18:24:24.331 23081-23081/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.fern.mangoeye, PID: 23081
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method boundingRect(Lorg/opencv/core/Mat;)Lorg/opencv/core/Rect; in class Lorg/opencv/imgproc/Imgproc; or its super classes (declaration of 'org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc' appears in /data/app/com.fern.mangoeye-jmLx1kABmB7GFFie5xaCyA==/base.apk!classes9.dex)
        at com.fern.mangoeye.OpenCVHandler.feedNewYUVData(OpenCVHandler.java:132)
        at com.fern.mangoeye.CameraView.onPreviewFrame(CameraView.java:140)
        at android.hardware.Camera$EventHandler.handleMessage(Camera.java:1221)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8167)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:496)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1100)
```

OpenCV initialization has `OpenCVLoader.initDebug()` as well as `BaseLoaderCallback`

OpenCV SDK version: 3.4.1
compileSdk: 31

Comment: Have you included the native libraries

Comment: @KaruneshPalekar Native libraries (`jni` folder) are copied to the libs folder in the project and are connected using `implementation group: 'org.bytedeco', name: 'opencv', version: '4.5.1-1.5.5', classifier: ....` but that didn’t bring any results either.

Comment: Typo. I mean `sdk\native\libs` folder. I tried to copy it's content to `app\libs` and `src\main\jniLibs`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by specifying `exclude group: 'org.bytedeco', module: 'opencv'` for `implementation (group: 'org.bytedeco', name: 'javacv', version: '1.5.5')` in `build.gradle`.
So now my dependencies looks like this:

```
dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
    implementation project(path: ':opencv')

    implementation 'org.jcodec:jcodec:0.2.5'
    
    implementation (group: 'org.bytedeco', name: 'javacv', version: '1.5.5'){
        exclude group: 'org.bytedeco', module: 'opencv'
    }

    implementation group: 'org.bytedeco', name: 'openblas', version: '0.3.13-1.5.5', classifier: 'android-arm'
    implementation group: 'org.bytedeco', name: 'openblas', version: '0.3.13-1.5.5', classifier: 'android-arm64'
    implementation group: 'org.bytedeco', name: 'openblas', version: '0.3.13-1.5.5', classifier: 'android-x86_64'
    implementation group: 'org.bytedeco', name: 'openblas', version: '0.3.13-1.5.5', classifier: 'android-x86'

    implementation group: 'org.bytedeco', name: 'ffmpeg', version: '4.3.2-1.5.5', classifier: 'android-arm'
    implementation group: 'org.bytedeco', name: 'ffmpeg', version: '4.3.2-1.5.5', classifier: 'android-arm64'
    implementation group: 'org.bytedeco', name: 'ffmpeg', version: '4.3.2-1.5.5', classifier: 'android-x86_64'
    implementation group: 'org.bytedeco', name: 'ffmpeg', version: '4.3.2-1.5.5', classifier: 'android-x86'
}
```

Also I created `jni` folder and copy folders from `sdk\native\libs` to it. So, the problem was with the initialization of OpenCV

Comment: That works, but it's easier to use javacv-platform or others like that with Gradle JavaCPP: https://github.com/bytedeco/gradle-javacpp#the-platform-plugin